# adjust rating based on number of experiences

Tags: data-transformation, rating, regularization

Suppose I am using a restaurant rating as an explanatory variable in a regression. The rating is  defined as $R=\frac{G}{G+B+N+S}$, where $G$ is good, $B$ is bad, $N$ is neutral and $S$ is silent. I have two conceptual issues. First, I want to adjust the rating when it's based on a small number of experiences, perhaps by shrinking it towards the overall mean. Second, people seem overly reluctant to rate highly-attended restaurants ($S$ is very high for places like the local joint that's been around for 30 years). If I plot ratings against $\ln(\text{experiences})$, I get an inverted U shape.

Are there any transformations that I can use to remedy these two issue?

Comment: Have you explored *directly* the relationships between $S,B,N,M$ and the dependent variable?

Comment: I fixed some notation above. Unfortunately I don't have all the data to do this, though I might be able to get it eventually. I have tried adding the full interaction between $R$ and the denominator of $R$, which is equivalent to adding $G$ and the denominator in the model. $G$ has a small positive effect and the denominator has a small negative effect. I also tried using the natural log of the denominator, with similar results.

Comment: What is your dependent variable?

Comment: The outcome is various measures of individual-level patronage (like check size, and number of meals).

Comment: @PeterFlom, I made *transfromation* a synonym for *data-transformation*, you can vote to approve the synonym [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/data-transformation/synonyms).

Comment: Hi, @Dimitriy, I swapped out the 'transfromation' tag, (for which this was the only question), w/ our fairly well-established 'data-transformation' tag, which I think does a good job of covering the subject you're asking about. If you disagree w/ this, feel free to rollback w/ my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

If the rating is fairly predictable based on the number of people who've been to the restaurant, it occurs to me that one possibility is to build a model of the ratings given experiences.  Then you could use the residuals (obviously, constant variance is fairly crucial here) instead of the raw data.